# Search for a row than write data to a specific column in that row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a membership database sheet "**Membership Database**" that contains all members details with usernames listed in column B. Column M contains the  total points balance a member has. Points are awarded for completing certain tasks. I also have an interface/form sheet "**PointsForm**".

Staff will type a members username into a cell and than select a task from a dropdown box. This task will be worth '**x**' points. When staff press submit it adds the points from completing the task to the members total point balance.

I have managed to create a cell with a dropdown where staff can type in a members username and it automatically adjusts as members join/leave. I have a dropdown cell where staff can select a task, this populates another cell displaying how many points it is worth. I need help trying to get the number of points added to the total points balance in the "**Members Database**". The part I am struggling with is trying to get it to search down Column `B` in the "**Members Database**" for the username that the staff member has selected. Than applying the points value in "**PointsForm**" `F10` to  Column `M` of that specific row only.

1. When a staff member clicks submit all the details from the input form go to a tracking sheet so I can see what staff has performed each adjustment and to which member. (Completed).
2. I have managed to get an error message if a staff tries to submit it without all fields completed.(Completed)
3. Managed to get the number of points to be adjusted to appear on the form. (Completed)
4. Staff can look up usernames in a specific cell. (Completed)
5. Getting the adjusted points added to total points balance in the "**Membership Database**" for the specific username selected. (Not Completed).

```
//Check Function Start

function checksubmitfinal() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form    = ss.getSheetByName("PointsForm"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calcs"); //Data Sheet
  var memsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Member Database"); //Mem Database

  //Input Values
var values = [[form.getRange("C8").getValue(),
                 form.getRange("F8").getValue(),
                 form.getRange("C10").getValue()]];

  //Check Blank Values
  for (i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
    if (values[0][i] == '') {
      var blankExists = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (blankExists) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please ensure all fields are completed.');
  }
  else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Points successfully logged!');
  }


 //Submit Function Start

  //Input Values
  var values = [[form.getRange("C8").getValue(),
                 form.getRange("F8").getValue(),
                 form.getRange("C10").getValue()]];
   
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 3).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Use `indexOf` [doc ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the match between the "members username" and name in the "Membership Database". `indexOf` will return a "index" number (which in your case will be a row number); use the row number plus the known Column number to write the new value to the database. Bear in mind that `indexOf` returns a zero-based value so you may need to add "1/one" to get the true row number - you can experiment with that. There are dozens of examples of use of `indexOf` on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

### RECOMMENDATION

**You can check this script out for your reference on how it works** (and to integrate with your overall script):

```
function addPoints() {
  const sheetName = "Membership";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // you can update the cell values to the actual cell values where you will be getting the staff input
  var values = [[ss.getRange("E1").getValue(),  // where the username's cell is
  ss.getRange("G1").getValue()]];               // where the points will be retrieved

  // gets an array of usernames from the membership database
  // this script gets the usernames from column B (row 1, col 2)
  var username = ss.getRange(1, 2, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  username.forEach((x, i) => {
    // checks if the username on the member array matches the entry
    // to update the total point balance
    if (x == values[0][0]) {
      // gets the current point balance on the username's row
      var bal = ss.getRange(`M${i + 1}`).getValue();
      // adds the new points to the total, and updates it on the sheet
      ss.getRange(`M${i + 1}`).setValue(bal + values[0][1]);
    }
  });
}
```

### OUTPUT

I also tried to integrate the script on a button to replicate the "Submit" button:

[image]

Comment: That's good to hear, you're welcome! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checksubmitfinal() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("PointsForm"); //Form Sheet
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Calcs"); //Data Sheet
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["C8","F8","C10"]);
  if (rgl.getRanges().find(rg => rg.isBlank())) {
    ui.alert('Please ensure all fields are completed.');
    return;
  } else {
    dsh.appendRow(rgl.getRanges().map(rg => rg.getValue()));
    ui.alert('Points successfully logged!'); 
  }
}
```